# Replace for-loop using apply in data-frame

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, apply

I am trying to improve the performance of a basic task I have to run relatively often. I have a dataframe 'test' that looks like this:

```
        pair_id rr  im  db
    1   A0A0B5JQ66_A0A0B5JFG2   NA  yes NA
    2   A0A024RA76_A0A024RA76   NA  yes NA
    3   A0A068F1B9_A0A068F1B9   NA  yes NA
    4   A0A098_A0A098   NA  yes NA
    5   A0A0B5JJY8_A0A0B5JFB4   yes NA  NA
    6   A0A0B5JK11_A0A0B5JK11   yes NA  NA
    7   A0A0B5JK74_A0A0B5JFG2   yes NA  NA
    8   A0A0B5JK74_A0A0B5JK74   yes NA  NA
    9   A0A0B5JKA2_A0A0B5JF96   NA  yes NA
    10  A0A0B5JKA2_A0A0B5JK74   NA  yes NA
    11  A0A0B5JPZ7_A0A0B5JFG2   yes yes NA
    12  A0A0B5JPZ7_A0A0B5JK74   NA  yes NA
    13  A0A0B5JPZ7_A0A0B5JKA2   NA  yes NA
    14  A0A0B5JPZ7_A0A0B5JPZ7   NA  yes NA
    15  A0A0B5JQ10_A0A0B5JK95   yes yes NA
    16  A0A0B5JQ14_A0A0B5JFB4   NA  yes NA
    17  A0A0B5JQ25_A0A0B5JFB4   NA  yes NA
    18  A0A0B5JQ25_A0A0B5JFB8   NA  yes NA
    19  A0A0B5JQ25_A0A0B5JK29   NA  yes NA
    20  A0A0B5JQ29_A0A0B5JQ14   yes NA  NA
```

I need to compare columns 2 and 3 ('rr' and 'im') and then set a value for column number 4 based on this comparison. For this I have created the following function called 'compare':

```
compare <- function(v){
  if (v[1]=="yes" & is.na(v[2])){
    db <- "rr"
  }
  else if (v[2]=="yes" & is.na(v[1])){
    db <- "im"
  }
  else if (v[1]=="yes" & v[2]=="yes"){
    db <- "both"
  }
  else {
    db <- "check"
  }
  db
}
```

It just takes a vector of two elements as input, checks which one has a value of "yes" and which one is empty (if any) and returns a value that can be assigned to a third column.

Now I have been using this in 'test' using a for-loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
        test[i,]$db <- compare(test[i,2:3])
}
```

This solution is however very inefficient when my data frames get to be large (I have to manage some with over 700000 rows) and takes a lot of time to compute. I have been trying to use my function under different variants of the 'apply' family, but could not make it work, since I am new to R and I do not have much experience with this set of functions. Any hints on an alternative that would improve preformance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this. It should give you a performance boost.

`library(dplyr)
 test <- mutate(test, db = ifelse(rr == "yes" & is.na(im), "rr", ifelse(is.na(rr) & im == "yes", "im", ifelse(rr == "yes" & im == "yes", "both", "check"))))`

Answer (score 2):

You could use an apply function

```
test$db <- apply(test[, 2:3], compare)
```

but this won't be much faster

A faster solution would be to make use of vectorisation

```
test$db <- "check" #make column of default values
test$db[test$rr == "yes" & is.na(test$im)] <- "rr"
test$db[test$im == "yes" & is.na(test$rr)] <- "im"
test$db[test$rr == "yes" & test$im == "yes"] <- "both"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone that gave an answer. I actually tried and compared the different approaches suggested with the original for-loop, using a 10000 lines-long test data frame. Here's what I got:

```
                   user   system elapsed
    ptm_loop      4.831    0.551   5.390
    ptm_apply     0.055    0.002   0.056
    ptm_vect      0.046    0.001   0.046
    ptm_dplyr     0.009    0.000   0.009
```

ptm is of course short for processing time and each of the proposed solutions are listed with a descriptive abbreviation. All of them give a significant boost to performance, but it seems that by far the fastest solution is the dplyr-based suggestion Psidom made.